# How to limit post per page of custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

Here's the codes i used to display the posts of my custom post "episode"

```
<?php
if( is_home() ){
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array('post_type'=>array('episodes',),'paged'=>$paged ) ); }  ?>
<?php  if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php post_movies_true(); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); {?>
```

How can i add post_per_page there to limit the posts of my custom post?

PS: i dont really know how to code im just trying to do some custom modification with the theme i bought. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `posts_per_page` in the args array to solve your problem.

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'episodes', ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'=>$paged,
) );
```

Read more on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify template, you can use the action [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and modify the `posts_per_page` parameter.

The code has to be in functions.php